# Python positive-lookbehind split variable-width

Tags: python, regex, string, split, lookbehind

I though that I have set up the expression appropriately, but the split is not working as intended.

```
c = re.compile(r'(?<=^\d\.\d{1,2})\s+');
for header in ['1.1 Introduction', '1.42 Appendix']:
    print re.split(c, header)
```

Expected result:

```
['1.1', 'Introduction']
['1.42',  'Appendix']
```

I am getting the following stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "foo.py", line 1, in 
>             c = re.compile(r'(?<=^\d.\d{1,2})\s+');
>        File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
>             return _compile(pattern, flags)
>        File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
>             raise error, v # invalid expression
>   sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
>   <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)

Comment: the error message says it - you can't have variable-length lookaround in python's regex engine.

Comment: Take a look at the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module, which allows variable-length lookbehind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookbehinds in python cannot be of variable width, so your lookbehind is not valid.

You can use a capture group as a workaround:

```
c = re.compile(r'(^\d\.\d{1,2})\s+');
for header in ['1.1 Introduction', '1.42 Appendix']:
    print re.split(c, header)[1:] # Remove the first element because it's empty
```

Output:

```
['1.1', 'Introduction']
['1.42', 'Appendix']
```

Comment: Do as long as the expression is not global, splitting in the first space is your approach. Sounds like it will work in my case.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It will be splitting on the first `(^\d\.\d{1,2})\s+` but the capture group means that it will keep the characters on which it has split too. It will split where your intended lookbehind was meant to split.

Answer (score 1):

your error in the regex is in the part `{1,2}` because Lookbehinds need to be fixed-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed.

try this [website](http://regex101.com/#python) to test your regex before you put it in code.

**BUT** in your case you don't need to use regex at all:

simply try this:

```
for header in ['1.1 Introduction', '1.42 Appendix']:
    print header.split(' ')
```

result:

```
['1.1', 'Introduction']
['1.42', 'Appendix']
```

hope this helps.

Comment: So; `*`, `+`, `{n}`, etc. are all not allowed?

Comment: `{n}` is allowed if `n` is a constant number like `1` or `2` or `5` ..etc. others are not allowed because the length is not constant. in short your length of characters should be constant.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may look lame. But you are checking only two digits after dot. So, you can use two lookbehind.

```
c = re.compile(r'(?:(?<=^\d\.\d\d)|(?<=^\d\.\d))\s+');
```