# Translate perl split to python split

Tags: python, regex, perl

In perl:

```
split(/(?<=[KR])/,$mystring)
```

splits mystring after every K or R via the two concepts "split between every character" (=empty string) + "lookbehind". So the sequence AAAKBBBBR becomes (AAAK,BBBBR).

Whats the counterpart in python? I cant find a way because the empty string does not split between characters!

Comment: look at the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748123/python-positive-lookbehind-split-variable-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need a look around? This regular expression should do it `[^KR]*[KR]`:

```
In [1]: import re                        # Import the regex library
In [2]: s = "AAAKBBBBR"                  # Define the input string
In [3]: re.findall(r'[^KR]*[KR]', s)     # Find all the matches in the string
Out[3]: ['AAAK', 'BBBBR']
```

Regexplanation:

```
[^KR] # ^ in character classes is negation so will match any character except K/R
*     # Quantifier used to match zero or more of the previous expression
[KR]  # Simple character class matching K/R
```

In words: *match zero or more characters that are not K/R that are followed by K/R.*

You might want to use the `+` quantifier to match at least one or more instead of `*` for cases like:

```
In [1]: import re    
In [2]: s = "KAAAKBBBBR"
In [3]: re.findall(r'[^KR]*[KR]', s)
Out[3]: ['K', 'AAAK', 'BBBBR']
In [4]: re.findall(r'[^KR]+[KR]', s)
Out[4]: ['AAAK', 'BBBBR']
```

To make the trailing `[KR]` optional you can use `?`:

```
In [5]: s = 'AAAKBBBBRAAA'
In [6]: re.findall(r'[^KR]+[KR]?', s)
Out[6]: ['AAAK', 'BBBBR', 'AAA']
```

Comment: can you give some further explanation please? whats the r, whats the ^ and whats the * ?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed as you are using look arounds already that you would understand the regular expression I proposed. I have added an explanation.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this because in the perl regex this case is covered: my sequence might look like AAAKBBBBRAAA and then i need AAAK, BBBBR and AAA as a result. So basically i need to split after each K and R and get all the substrings, including the last one!

Comment: thank you! i find the perl expression easier and more intuitive to be honest ... :)

Comment: It's true that Python doesn't have native regex strings like `perl` but under the hood it's using `libpcre` *(perl compliant regular expression)* so any functionality in with perl regexs should be doable from python, you just need to the functions https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: one more question: why do we need to put that r ? r means raw, so r'\n' does not match a newline but a backslash followed by an n (according to python doc). so if we use r in this case, why doesnt he match [, followed by ^, followed by K ecetera ... ?

Comment: We don't actually need to use a raw string here for this example but it's good practice. A raw string means that Python doesn't do any interpretation of the string, usaully when you actually want to match a literal `\` for instance, it doesn't stop regex functions from correctly interpreting the regex however.

Comment: awww man he matches an empty substring as last hit ... this is so annoying, cant find a satisfying solution.

Comment: @user3182532 make sure you are `+` instead of `*`

Comment: but then KAAKBBKAA does not split into K,AAK, BBK, AA :(

Comment: So then do `[^KR]+[KR]?|[KR]`.

Comment: Thanks. Im a bit disapointed to not have found such a beautiful solution as the perl regex (thought it was possible) but thanks alot!

Comment: +1 for showing that matching can often be used instead of splitting. :)